# Pass data from view to controller method

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I need to use the name of the current view in a method in my controller
I am able to get the name with the code below in my view.

I will like to pass this @ViewData["pageName"] to my MakeChange action result
in my controller. Each time I step through the MakeChange method all I get 
is "object reference not set to an instance of an object"

How can I pass data from my view to controller method ?

```
            @ViewData["pageName"] =  @Path.GetFileName(Server.MapPath(VirtualPath))


             public ActionResult MakeChange(string lang)
                    {
                        string getPageName = ViewData["pageName"].ToString();

                        return RedirectToAction(getPageName, "Home");
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass data from view to controller using ViewData. You can use ViewData to pass data from Controller to your view.

To achieve what you want, you can do as follows:

```
<input type='hidden' name='lang' value='@Path.GetFileName(Server.MapPath(VirtualPath))' />

<input type='submit' value='send'>
```

Ps: you should put the input's inside a form tag.

Comment: Thanks. So how do I retrieve this from the controller method? Is it like a request ?

Comment: Model binding will transfer the value of the hidden field (using the name attribute) to the variable you're expecting in your MakeChange action

Comment: here some other samples: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20333225 and http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/576514/AplusBeginner-splusTutorialplusonplusVariousplus

Comment: Unfortunately, I am using jquery click event for the submit button. My page is not doing a post. How do I handle that?

Comment: http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/220/posting-data-with-jquery-ajax-in-asp-net-razor-web-pages

Answer (score 0):

`Path.GetFileName(Server.MapPath(VirtualPath))` will give you the razor view name with extension (Ex : `index.cshtml`). You can not use that with `RedirectToAction` method as RedirectToAction method is looking for an action method name. You need to trim down the file extension part before using it.

To send this to the controller action, you can keep the value inside a hidden field inside your form. When user posts the form, it will be available in your HttpPost action method. You need to make sure that there is a parameter which has same name as the hidden field's name value.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
   <input type="text" name="lang" value="English" />
   <input type="hidden" name="pageName" 
                                 value="@Path.GetFileName(Server.MapPath(VirtualPath))" />

   <input id="BtnAdd" type="submit" value="Save" />

}
```

So your action method will be

```
public ActionResult MakeChange(string lang,string pageName)
{
   var viewName=pageName;
   //Get rid of the extension.
   viewName = viewName.Replace(".cshtml","");
   return RedirectToAction(viewName , "Home");
}
```

Even if you are doing an ajax post, it will still work, just serialize your form and send it

```
$("#BtnAdd").click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   var _this = $(this); 
   $.post("@Url.Action("MakeChange","Home")",_this.closest("form").serialize(),
                                                                       function(response){

        //do something with response
    });
});
```

There are more clean ways of getting the view name without the file extension trimming approach we did. Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34188825/40521).